# Problem getting jQuery script to work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I am new to jQuery. I want a simple list. I just want to show and hide the additional details.

```
<ul>
  <li><div onclick="show()"><img src="product_pic" />Product 1</div><div id="details" class="hide">short intro about the product</div></li>
<ul>
```

CSS

```
.hide {display: none;}
```

jQuery

```
function show(){
     $(this).next().toggleClass('hide');
}
```

It is not working. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. It's `toggleClass`, not `toggleclass`
2. Hook up the event handler using jQuery, rather than using the old-style attributes.

So:

```
$("div.hide").prev().click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('hide');
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/orehu4)

How that works:

- We find the divs that have that "hide" class, and then we find all of their immediate predecessors via [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/). That creates a set of all of the divs who are immediately followed by the `div.hide` divs.
- We hook the `click` event on the predecessors.
- When the `click` happens, we toggle the class on the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element after the one that was clicked.

I think I'd recommend you use a separate "details" class or something alongside "hide", in case you want to use "hide" somewhere else that won't have this precise structure. And if you do that, you can show and hide without changing the class; jQuery's smart enough to override the CSS "display: none" bit, even when applied by a rule (not all libs are). That would look like this:

CSS:

```
.details {
    display: none;
}
```

Markup:

```
<li><div><img src="product_pic" />Product 1</div><div class="details">short intro about the product</div></li>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("div.details").prev().click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll("div.details:first").toggle();
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/orehu4/2)

Note that uses [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) rather than `toggleClass`.

---

**Side note**: I note you have `id="details"` on the details `div`. Remember that `id` values **must** be unique, so if you have more than one of these, you can't use "details" as the `id` of each of them.

Comment: @T.J.C Thanx for your reply. I want to toggleclass of the next div(description) that is hidden, When I click on the product div. One more thing should I use each method as I have many products. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ivanka: Yeah, just fixed it (the next div thing). And no, you don't need `each`, because `click` will hook up the event on each of the divs.

Comment: @Ivanka: I've updated my answer to solve the "selector_for_div" part, which is a bit trickier than usual. The above can just drop right in, and has a live example.

Comment: @T.J.C Wow I didn't know it was so complex, I appreciate your help. One last thing is there a way to add a class to <li> that is holding both the div's. Thanx Again it works great:-)

Comment: @Ivanka: It's actually pretty simple, really, but the explanation can make it look complex. Sure, you can readily add a class to the `li` by using `$(this).parent()` to get to it and calling `addClass`. See: http://api.jquery.com/parent/ and just generally http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/. Best,

Answer (score 0):

1 . Change "toggleclass" for "toggleClass".
2 . You can try this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <div class="show"><img src="product_pic" />Product 1</div>
      <div id="details" class="hide">short intro about the product</div>
  </li>
<ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.show').bind('click', function(ev){
     $(this).next('div').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

CSS

```
.hide {display: none;}
```

**EDIT**

If you're going to have multiple tags "li", you should remove the ID "details" because it would be repeated, and must be unique. your html code could be next:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <div class="show"><img src="product_pic" />Product 1</div>
      <div class="details hide">short intro about the product</div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="show"><img src="product_pic" />Product 2</div>
      <div class="details hide">other short intro about the product</div>
  </li>
<ul>
```

OR

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <div class="show"><img src="product_pic" />Product 1</div>
      <div id="details-prod-1" class="hide">short intro about the product</div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="show"><img src="product_pic" />Product 2</div>
      <div id="details-prod-2" class="hide">other short intro about the product</div>
  </li>
<ul>
```